# How can i compute the probability that a cloud of points was created by a probability distribution?

Tags: probability-distributions

I have a number of probability distributions that describe a number of points. like this:
[image: prob]

Now if i have draw a one point out of each distribution, i get a bunch of points randomly set on the 2-dimensional surface. How can i, given the set of probability distributions and a set of points compute the probability that i would draw something like that again? What is the correct mathematical term for what i want to compute?

Comment: [Likelihood](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Likelihood_function)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your question right, then what you want is to develop a statistical test.

Essentially, given some sampling of points $P = \left\{ p_1, p_2,\ldots,p_n\right\}$, you need to estimate the probability that this sampling of points resulted from some distribution. In this case, your null hypothesis is that $P$ was drawn from your presumed distribution. You will want to set a threshold for *statistical significance*. In other words, there is no concrete, deterministic way to distinguish between a set of points happening to randomly align with your chosen distribution by sheer luck, or whether they actually came from your distribution.

There are many such tests; a basic example is a [chi-squared test](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pearson%27s_chi-squared_test). Off-hand, I don't know which test is best for your application, but the Wikipedia page should direct you to some good information.